# VBA copy value of named_range into TextBox

Tags: vba, textbox, named-ranges

The named range (or user defined range) has 6 columns, but number of rows may change based on other functions.

Now trying to get the entire value of that range, of all 6 columns and all rows into a TextBox. Rows delimited by tab.

Following code returns object defined error etc.

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("named_range").Value
```

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:

FunThomas is right, I won'e be able to get the value of the range without declaring it an separate line. So I started with the below code which works well in displaying the range in a multiline msgBox.

How do I get rid of the extra InputBox, and display results in UserForm1.TextBox1 instead of the msgBox which has limited functionality.

```
Sub showOfferRange()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
  xTxt = ThisWorkbook.Names("offers_running")
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Offer range:", "Display offers", xTxt, , , , , 8)
'Set xRg = xTxt
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   On Error Resume Next
For xRow = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
    For xCol = 1 To xRg.Columns.Count
        xStr = xStr & xRg.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value & vbTab
    Next
    xStr = xStr & vbCrLf
Next
    MsgBox xStr
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure how the link is related to my question.

Comment: Probably you want to access `sheet1` of a workbook, but you are accessing a variable named `sheet1`. So I asssume you need something like `thisWorkbook.sheets("sheet1")` or `activeWorkbook.sheets("sheet1")`, but this is only guessing. The link explains how to access the workbook and worksheet objects.

Comment: Sorry, just learned that you can access a sheet by its name ("codeName") as object - was not aware about that. If sheet doesn't exists, you will get an error `424 - Object required`. If this is not your error, try to split your code into 2 lines by assigning the value of the range into a variant variable and then assign this variable to you userform. Which line throws the error?

Comment: I edited the question with new code. Almost there need some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to write the text into the textbox of the form, it´s just

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.text = UserForm1.TextBox1
UserForm1.show
```

As you have multiple lines, don´t forget to set the `MultiLine`-Property of the textbox to `true`.

Another point: You should change the lines where you read the range. The `on error resume next` is a very dangerous statement as it eat up all errors and you can get completly lost to find a bug. It's only needed to catch the case that the inputbox doesn't return a `Range` (for example because Cancel was pressed). So I suggest you change the steatements to

```
xTxt = ThisWorkbook.Names("offers_running")
Set xRg = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Offer range:", "Display offers", xTxt, , , , , 8)
On Error Goto 0
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Works great and thank you for the suggestion! One last question how do I get rid of the inputBox? I don't want this extra step. When I use Set xRg = xTxt, I get type mismatch error. Probably trying to pass a string as a range.